# I'm surprised he should + infinitive

Tags: should

To what time do such sentences refer? I mean the part after **should**.

**1 I'm surprised he should complain about your stay there.**

Does it mean that the stay is in the past/present/future?

**2 I'm surprised he should be giving lecture in a church.**

When is the lecture? In the past/present/future?

Comment: They refer to the time that has already been referred to in the context. In the first, when did you, or will you, stay there, or are you there now? Whatever the answer is, that is the time referred to.

Comment: My take is that there may be a problem with your use of the word "should". The first sentence would make more sense with *would*, in which case the stay would have been in the past, with the complaining taking place after the stay. The second sentence might also make more sense with "would", in which case the lecture would also be in the past; otherwise you would say you're surprised he "will be" giving a lecture in a church. Not sure how this jives with the comment of @Greybeard.

Comment: I take it as you speak american English, Richard.